Why can I not un-CW my one question that was CW-ed?
Some kind soul decided that a question I posted should be CW. Fine. Everybody is entitled to their opininion.  I even have mine, and I don't think someone should swoop in that just flip question.
Feel free to suggest to owners of questions to exercise an option of converting.
Not asking and conversion-without-headsup is uncool.

On other sites, mods will often remove CW status from a post if you flag the post and ask them too. Don't know how things work here.

I believe that SO took away the ability for someone to convert their own question into CW after it has been asked.  It is now the moderator's judgement as to when this should be applied.  I just confirmed this by going to one of my own questions and editing it: the CW check box no longer exists.
So the old behavior of requesting the OP to make their question CW no longer is an option.  That being said, I've always thought that people should have the capacity in some way to convert back from CW to non-CW; that has never existed as an option.

Thanks for added color. Still seems like deficient design to me.

Yep; I don't totally understand why they did that.  There's a lot of confusion/angst around the whole CW feature, in part because many questions that probably shouldn't be asked at all (based on SO's FAQ) are just being set as CW instead of closed.

thanks for letting us know, shane. there should absolutely be a way to convert back from cw. esp when the original mark/marker was simply inaccurate/capricious
